# Issue with textarea in PHP

Tags: php

I have the following code.

```
print("  <form action='home.php' method='POST'>
            <textarea name='changemainhometa' id='msgpost'> $home </textarea>
            <input type='submit' name='changemainhomefinal' value='Change' />
         </form> ");
```

The value `$home` is extracted from the database

Now I change the text in the textarea and press submit.

Then, the following code is executed:

```
$value = $_POST["changemainhometa"];
print($value);
$query = mysql_query("UPDATE contentdata 
                      SET text = $value 
                      WHERE key = 'home' ");  
print("Succesvol gewijzigd");
```

But now, every time i execute this code, it does not update, but it sets `$value` to the old variable from the database, instead of the new one which I entered in the textarea

Btw., `id:msgpost` is from the yahoo text editor.

Comment: Lads I fixed it, it was a problem within the textarea, thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: you should answer your own question by posting an answer and then ticking it off, so that your question will appear as "closed".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it already, it was an error in the YUI simple editor, which did not allow me to submit data, for future reference, i fixed this with `submitHandle:true` in the configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You are dropping an unescaped, unquoted string into the middle of your query. Except for very specific input, it is going to error (or run an SQL injection attack).

Use [bound parameters](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) to include variables in your SQL, don't mash strings together.

Comment: But the main problem was, that it did not change the textarea value after editing and submitting it

Answer (score 1):

This query:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE contentdata 
                  SET text = $value 
                  WHERE key = 'home' ");
```

Will generate an error, saying your query is incorrect, so nothing will be updated. Have you enabled error reporting? If so, you should see an warning or error.

If you add single quotes around $value (so `SET text = '$value'`) will solve this issue, but be sure to properly escape database input (using `mysql_real_escape_string()`, or even better, using prepared statements).

Comment: Prepared statements won't help with the escaping, bound paramaters will (it is just that people tend to start using the two things at the same time and together).

Answer (score -4):

```
'UPDATE contentdata 
                      SET text = \''.$value.'\' 
                      WHERE key = \'home\'';
```

Comment: Vulnerable to SQL injection. Don't do that.

Comment: Correction, it has syntax errors so it just won't work: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in - on line 2`

Comment: Does not fix the issue, but thanks for the input, it makes my code cleaner.

Comment: And the dot is in the wrong place, it should be after the ", not between the ' and the "

Comment: Sorry it was fast fix ....yup there are mistakes. Dot should be out of string indeed.

Comment: @Quentin: This question is not about vulnerability of code, but overall functionality. So in this case goal is to achieve working code. But from the security point of view I totally agree with you.

Comment: The overall functionality being that it might do what is intended, or it might throw an SQL error, or it might delete data etc depending on what the input is? Working code works regardless of the input.

Comment: I agree with you - totally . But the question overall stands in a form  - "What mistake I have made in this lines?" ;)

Comment: The mistake is to give bad code, that others will copy without thinking, thus making their systems vulnerable …

Comment: I see , will take into account next time. Thank you.